# Iterated Functions - designing iterator to converge to constant value

Tags: convergence-divergence, recursion

I came across an interesting iterated function:
$$
x_n = \frac{x_{n-1}}{x_{n-1} + b}
$$
This is an extremely simple example and it converges to the constant $1-b$.

Can someone provide some insight to what this is or how it was come up with?  Has anyone ever seen it?

It seems similar to the newton-raphson division problem where an iterated function can be used to converge to a reciprocal:
$$
x = x(2-Nx) \to \frac {1}{N}. 
$$

Comment: If the result is the only thing that you are looking for. The quick way is treat your equation as $x = \frac{x}{x + b}$ and solve.

Comment: For an approach that gives nice intuition, draw the [web diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobweb_plot).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if $$f(x) = \frac{x}{x+b}$$ then $$f(x) < x$$ when $$\frac{x}{x+b} - x < 0$$ which means $$\frac{-b}{x+b} < 0.$$ If $0 < b < 1$ then this holds provided $x > -b$.

Thus as long as $x_0 > 0$ then the sequence you describe is decreasing. Moreover, since all the terms are positive with initial choice of $x_0 >0$, the sequence must converge to some limit $L$.

Thus $$L = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{x_n + b} = \frac{L}{L+b}$$ which yields the equation $$L^2 + (b-1)L = 0$$ which tells us that either $L=0$ or $L=1-b$.

If our initial value $x_0 < 1-b$ then $L$ must be zero, since the sequence is decreasing.

Now suppose that $x_0 > 1-b$. We wish to show that $f(x) > 1-b$ whenever $x> 1-b$. Once this is established, then $L=1-b$ when $x_0 > 1-b$.

Comment: thanks.  have you seen iterated functions of this type?  I wonder how one would design such types of iterators that would converge to desired constants....

Comment: I have seen these come up in practice. Generally if you want to show anything like this converges its a two step process: Show it is bounded and monotonic, then try to solve for the limit that is guaranteed by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: If you are looking for something that in more general, then I would suggest you look at a contraction, and the Banach Fixed Point theorem. There are a few books on Dynamical Systems and Ergodic theory that would have more things about this.

Comment: Correction above, the equation would give results L=0 or L=1-b.  This would be consistent with that I said about: that the iteration converges to (1-b).

Comment: Oh you are right. Typo. Also, you might be interested in a book along the lines of Complex Dynamics by Carleson and Gamelin. Just as a start. Or on the cheaper end of things, Fractals Everywhere is a good start.